# Magento 2 multi-select field in block not displaying values in magento admin panel

Tags: magento2, multiselect

**I have created custom form in which I want a multi select field and display dynamic data. I have created a collection object in the form of array and passing it as a value for my multi select field.**

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'collection_block',
            'multiselect', 
            array(
            'name'=>'collection_block[]',    
            'label'=>'Collection Blocks',
            'value' => $collectionCheckboxes
        ));
```

> $collectionCheckboxes is an array of values which has dynamic data.

I am able to get the multi select design in admin panel but my values not displayed.

Can anyone suggest with some solution.

**Thanks**

Comment: Avoid to use php block system. Try using ui component.

Comment: I have almost completed everything related to this form and am just left with this as of now can i get some solutions on this?